# Why is Surah Fatiha in the first person?

Tags: quran, tafseer, quran-recitation, quran-translation

I want to understand that why did Allah, may he be glorified and exalted, reveal Surah Fatiha in the first person. I had this doubt since some time but it developed more today when I read this as a so called -"mistake" in the Noble Quran by an anti-Islamic site. Astagfirullah but I am sure that I will get my answer In sha Allah.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand your Question at all.

Comment: @Medi1Saif do u not see that in Surah Fatiha it looks we speak in First person unlike in other places of the Qur'an where we speak the words of Allah swt. ?

Comment: Well there are other surah and verses for which this applies too!

Comment: @Medi1Saif verses I have seen but not Surahs because I remember reading Qul or something similar in beginning of the Surah

Answer (score 3):

The surah is a prayer. Had there been a 'قُلْ' (Say) in the beginning, just like the last two surahs, the objection wouldn't have arisen at the very first place. It would have meant that God took the initiative to ***teach*** mankind how to pray for guidance. However, a different style has been adopted here by dropping it. Why? Javed Ahmad Ghamidi offers an [explanation](http://www.monthly-renaissance.com/issue/content.aspx?id=334):

> This sūrah is a prayer to seek guidance from the Almighty for the
>   straight path – a prayer which was the wish of every upright person in
>   the time of the Prophet Muhammad (sws). After the Jews and the
>   Christians had distorted the face of religion through their
>   innovations and deviations, it was in fact the desire of every heart
>   to receive fresh guidance. The Almighty ***articulated this desire***
>   through the tongue of His Prophet (sws) in these eternal and matchless
>   words.

In short, the surah has been revealed thus to preserve the direction of discourse.

And God knows the best!